# Custom token and Windows Identity Foundation

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-security, wif

I have a webservice where I want to have authorization. But for login user must put username, password and his company identifier. Standard WCF authentications classes only support username and password so I've decided to create custom credentials with custom token. I see custom token sample application from Microsoft ([wcf sample description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731872%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)) and I'm able to run it. But now the real problem. On the server side I want to use Windows Identity Foundation (without STS - authorization should be performed in custom SecurityTokenHandler. I've created this handler:

```
public class MyCustomTokenHandler : SecurityTokenHandler
{
    public override string[] GetTokenTypeIdentifiers()
    {
        //this is invoked correctly
        return new string[] { Constants.CreditCardTokenNamespace };
    }
    public override Type TokenType
    {
        get
        {
            //this is invoked correctly
            return typeof(CreditCardToken);
        }
    }

    public override bool CanReadToken(XmlReader reader)
    {
        //this is invoked correctly
        if (reader.IsStartElement(Constants.CreditCardTokenName, Constants.CreditCardTokenNamespace))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public override SecurityToken ReadToken(XmlReader reader)
    {
        //read token code - it is invoked correctly
    }

    public override bool CanValidateToken
    {
        get
        {//this is not invoked
            return true;
        }
    }

    public override ClaimsIdentityCollection ValidateToken(SecurityToken token)
    {
        //this is not invoked
        IClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity();
        identity.Claims.Add(new Claim(WSIdentityConstants.ClaimTypes.Name, "Test"));

        return new ClaimsIdentityCollection(new IClaimsIdentity[] { identity });
    }
}
```

For test purposes I've created the second handler which inherits from UserNameSecurityTokenHandler:

```
public class CustomUserNameSecurityTokenHandler : UserNameSecurityTokenHandler
{
    public override bool CanValidateToken
    {
        get
        {//this is invoked but it shouldn't!!!
            return true;
        }
    }

    public override ClaimsIdentityCollection ValidateToken(SecurityToken token)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I've registered them in the web.config:

```
<microsoft.identityModel>
<service>
  <securityTokenHandlers>
    <remove type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.WindowsUserNameSecurityTokenHandler, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add type="Microsoft.Samples.CustomToken.CustomUserNameSecurityTokenHandler, CreditCardToken"/>
    <add type="Microsoft.Samples.CustomToken.MyCustomTokenHandler, CreditCardToken"/>
  </securityTokenHandlers>     
</service>
```

The client application sends my CreditCardToken correctly (this is the client from wcf sample application). But on the webservice side I have the following behavior:

1. TokenType and GetTokenTypeIdentifiers from MyCustomTokenHandler are invoked (good)
2. Methods CanReadToken and ReadToken from MyCustomTokenHandler are invoked (good)
3. Methods CanValidateToken and ValidateToken from MyCustomTokenHandler are not invoked (wrong)
4. Method CanValidateToken from CustomUserNameSecurityTokenHandler is invoked (wrong because client application sent different token)
5. In the finall I get exception:

> Cannot find a token authenticator for the 'Microsoft.Samples.CustomToken.CreditCardToken' token type. Tokens of that type cannot be accepted according to current security settings.

The message tells about token authenticator for this type of token but what I know that the token handler from WIF is used for such purpose.

Could you tell me what I should do to force WIF to use MyCustomTokenHandler for validation (authentication)?